# TD height works on element but not from CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some table cells that I want to set a height for. 
It works exactly like it should when I set the height directly on the element:

```
<td class="row-separator" style="height: 5px;"></td>
```

But when I try to do it from the CSS at the top of my page it doesn't work:

```
td.row-separator {
  height: 5px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

All the other CSS properties are applied, but not the height. This happens in both Firefox and IE. What could be causing this?

Comment: I assume there's other CSS that affects the height of the td, too. Since Inline styles are meant to override any external definitions, it might apply due to that. You can easily check that in the inspector of your webbrowser.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/d9uygvL1/) that doesn't show any difference.

Comment: @connexo that was my first thought too, but this is the very last page-level CSS declaration in the head of the page.

Comment: Using a cell as a row separator is a semantic error in the first place. You should be looking at a border on a row, or grouping rows with `tbody` elements.

Comment: @voodoo-burger — Order of rule-sets is not the most important thing for determining the cascade order. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

Comment: It's ***absolutely essential*** to learn about CSS rule specificity. Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: **Please use your webbrowser's inspector to verify the problem cause.**

Comment: @connexo I will definitely check out that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There must be other CSS** that affects the `height` of the `td`, too. Since inline styles (those declared in the `style` attribute directly on the HTML element) are meant to *override* any external definitions, it might apply due to that. You can easily check that in the inspector of your webbrowser.

See these two examples:

```css
#box p {
  font-size: 32px;
}
p.some-text {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p class="some-text">This is 32px because #box makes the selector way more specific than p.some-text</p>
  <p class="some-text" style="font-size: 16px;">Inline styles have the highest specificity and can only be overwritten using !important (which you should not)</p>
</div>
```

(Hint, even though your code does not have it: This example also demonstrates why you should not make use of `#id` selectors in your CSS.)

To learn more about CSS "prioritization" (which is called *specificity*), you can start here:

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @Quentin's comment on my original question and using !important from @Sebastian Brosch's answer solves the problem is: height is being inherited from an element above, even though the `row-separator` CSS declaration comes later. I guess inheritance isn't always 100% top-down.

Comment: As I said, it's inevitable to understand CSS specificity (at least the basics of it) to know what is going on. **Never** use `!important;` unless you know exactly *why* it is absolutely **unavoidable** in that specific case.

Comment: Note that `!important` can be used as a debugging tool. If adding `!important` works, then you will know it's a specificity issue. If it doesn't, then there's an error somewhere else!

Comment: As long as you know exactly what you are doing and *why* you are doing it, it's certainly perfectly okay to use `!important`. It *does* have its valid use-cases.